# The best way for benchmarks (performance analysis) in R?

Tags: r, package, benchmarking

I am currently testing some of my performance critical algorithms in R and I am looking for a simple way to do these benchmarks and get a clear summary. So I found the `rbenchmark` package which is frequently used. But this does not really suit my needs. My algorithms usually depend on some parameters or there are different "typical" data sets which should be possible to test in batch.

My current quick-n-dirty-solution is (with a quite silly but simple example where max/median is tested on 10^6 and on 5*10^6 random numbers)

```
library(rbenchmark)
multi.benchmarks <- function(..., settings) {
  res <- NULL
  for (i in 1:length(settings)) {
    env <- new.env()
    eval(settings[[i]], env)
    tres <- benchmark(..., environment = env)
    res <- rbind(res, cbind(names(settings)[i], tres))
  }
  names(res)[1] <- "setting"
  return(res)
}

multi.benchmarks(mean = expression(mean(x)), median = expression(median(x)), 
                 settings = list(s1 = expression({x <- runif(1E6)}), 
                                 s2 = expression({x <- runif(5E6)})), 
                 replications = 3)
```

This returns:

```
  setting   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1      s1   mean            3    0.00       NA      0.00     0.00         NA        NA
2      s1 median            3    0.16       NA      0.14     0.01         NA        NA
3      s2   mean            3    0.03        1      0.04     0.00         NA        NA
4      s2 median            3    0.57       19      0.51     0.07         NA        NA
```

which is more or less that what I want, but I am still missing:

- A simpler syntax (expressions are read via `substitute(...)`, etc.) and
- more possible params - e.g. 
  `my_benchmark(algorithm(dataset, a, b), algorithm = list(func1, func2), a = list(1,2), b = list(10, 20), replications = 3)`would be a nice way to run 8 different benchmarks: For all combinations of func1/func2 and all possible values of `a` and `b`.
- Detect which params are not needed: If `func1`has parameters `a` and `b` and `func2` just has a parameter `a` but not `b`, then we will have only 6 possible combinations.
- More detailed output, e.g. an option to get additional columns for the mean value and the standard deviation of all the runtimes after N replications.

Probably it would cost me just a couple of days to write a benchmark package which is able do to all these things and still has some kind of downward compatibility to rbenchmark, but before I start to do this, I would like to ask you:

- Are there other recommendable benchmark solutions for R which I should consider?
- Do you think a more sophisticated benchmark package with such functions would be of general interest in the R community? (I am thinking about a new package)

Comment: See Hadley Wickham's [Performance](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html)

Answer (score 2):

"Looking for a tool" questions are no longer seen as appropriate so someone will shoot this down shortly.

But look at `microbenchmark`, it at least returns the set of results too so you can do more summaries -- I used that for some custom 'violin' plots in the RcppZiggurat package / vignette.

Last but not least, a new 'meta' benchmark package may well make sense especially if you integrate it nicely with the existing timing / profiling / benchmarking packages rather than reinventing (more or less) the same wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with `microbenchmark`! I know that questions here should not be discussions about opinions, but I hoped that providing my existing approach focuses this question on the technical aspects of benchmarking in R.